# Prolog: How do I make repeating print/input statements?

Tags: recursion, io, prolog

I'm using SWISH Prolog to create a 'chatbot' that stops when the user writes "quit." So far this is my code:

```
chat :-
    write('hello I am a chatbot'),
    nl,
    write('when you see "user:" type a word followed by "."'),
    nl,
    write('or type "stop." if you want to stop this nonsense!'),
    read(X);
    reply(X).

reply(X) :-
    X = 'quit' -> print('Goodbye'), !; write(":P"),
    write("did you want "),
    write(X),
    write('?'),
    read(Newx);
    reply(Newx).
```

When it runs I expect it to write the value of X in the print statement, but it outputs 'did you want [null value]?' instead of 'did you want [x]?' ([x] being the inputted value of x). The if statement always returns true (pretty sure that has something to do with strings, but I have no idea how to fix it) and when I took it out to test the rest of the code, it only runs the one instance of the reply function. It doesn't seem to recurse, even though the statement is there.

3 questions: How do I pass X to be shown in reply(X), how do I make the reply function actually recurse, and how do string comparisons work in Prolog?

Update: fixed capitalization of variables & punctuation (';' when there should've been ',' in read statements). That fixed literally everything lol

Comment: variables start with an upper case letter. So you would use `X` instead of `x` nad `NewX` instead of `newx`.

Comment: @gusbro changed it and it reads the input now, thank you!